# how to handle Sonarlint java:S2259 (Null pointers should not be dereferenced)

Tags: java, sonarlint-intellij

```
if (res.getBody() == null || res.getBody().getServiceResult() == null) {
  return; //
}
```

in above code,
sonarlint complains that
SonarLint: A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getBody()" can return null. (from res.getBody().getServiceResult() )

I think "res.getBody() == null" checks null first so it should go to return line, not reach to next if condition.

Am I thinking something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `res.getBody() == null || res.getBody().getServiceResult() == null)`

Sonar detects that `res.getBody()` can be null when you do the check `res.getBody()==null`.

After that, you call `res.getBody()` again.

It could be non-null the first time but not the second time, sonar does not know this.

In order to fix this, just do the following:

```java
BodyType body=res.getBody();
if (body == null || body.getServiceResult() == null) {
  return;
}
```

You can then even reuse `body` after that.

If you are absolutely sure that `res.getBody()` stays null and is also not modified by another thread, you could also use a `//NOSONAR` comment in order to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems res also can be null.

Try

```
if (res == null || res.getBody() == null || res.getBody().getServiceResult() == null) {
  return; //
}
```

Such long getter chains can also be replaced with Optional + map + ifPresent lambda style.